# Display all iterations of for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I created a method that calculates and displays values of simple interest based on the amount of years. I want to show all years so for example if the years is 5, I want to show the value for years 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

This is my code so far

```
    public static String numbers(String method, double principal, double rate, double years) {

    double simpleInterest = principal + (principal * (rate / 100) * years);
    String interest = "";
    for (double digit = 1; digit <= years; digit++) {
        if (method.equals("Simple")) {
            interest = "Principal: $" + principal + ',' + " Rate: " + rate + "\n" + "Year  Simple Interest Amount\n"
                    + digit + "-->$" + simpleInterest;
        }
    }
    return interest;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print(numbers("Simple", 5000, 5, 5));
}
```

My output is

```
Principal: $5000.0, Rate: 5.0
Year  Simple Interest Amount
5.0-->$6250.0
```

But I want it to also display the previous years like

```
Principal: $5000.0, Rate: 5.0
Year  Simple Interest Amount
1.0-->$5250.0
2.0-->$5500.0
3.0-->$5750.0
4.0-->$6000.0
5.0-->$6250.0
```

What do I need to do to display the previous years?

Comment: What did you try?  I mean, not going to lie, you already coded it, just didnt print it.

Comment: First you are not calculating the interest, but the total owed if no payments are made. So I'm assuming you rename `interest` to `total` below. You can either put a print statement inside the computation loop, or you'll have to return the annual totals as a list,  like `totals=[]` before the loop to make an empty list, then `totals.append(total)` inside the loop, finally `return totals`

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate `simpleInterest` for every year `simpleInterest = principal + (principal * (rate / 100) * digit);` here `digit` represent `year`.

and also use `+=` operator to concatenate results to `interest` and `return` it.
You can also use string `concat()` method 
Here is the syntax of this method: `public String concat(String s)`.
you can use it like this: `interest = interest.concat(digit + "-->$" + simpleInterest + "\n");`

```
public static String numbers(String method, double principal, double rate, double years) {

        double simpleInterest = principal + (principal * (rate / 100) * years);
        String interest = "";
        System.out.println("Principal: $" + principal + ',' + " Rate: " + rate + "\n"+ "Year  Simple Interest Amount\n");
        for (double digit = 1; digit <= years; digit++) {
            if (method.equals("Simple")) {
                simpleInterest = principal + (principal * (rate / 100) * digit);
                interest +=  digit + "-->$" + simpleInterest + "\n";
            }
        }
        return interest;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print(numbers("Simple", 5000, 5, 5));
    }
```

> **Output:**

```
Principal: $5000.0, Rate: 5.0
Year  Simple Interest Amount

1.0-->$5250.0
2.0-->$5500.0
3.0-->$5750.0
4.0-->$6000.0
5.0-->$6250.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (method.equals("Simple")) {
            interest = "Principal: $" + principal + ',' + " Rate: " + rate + "\n" + "Year  Simple Interest Amount\n"
                    + digit + "-->$" + simpleInterest;
        }
```

in the code above you are reassigning `interest` if `method` is equal to `"simple"`. so, the last assigned value is returned.

use `+=` to concatenate new results to `interest` or just return `String[]` containing each result as an individual element and then iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

public static String numbers(String method, double principal, double rate, double years)
        {

```
        String interest = "";
        for (double digit = 1; digit <= years; digit++)
        {
            if (method.equals(Simple))
            {
                double simpleInterest = principal + (principal * (rate / 100) * digit);
                interest += "Principal: $" + principal + ',' + " Rate: " + rate + "\n" + "Year  Simple Interest Amount\n"
                        + digit + "-->$" + simpleInterest;                   
            }
        }
        return interest;
    }
```

Comment: You needed to append to string interest using "+=" for every year. Otherwise it will change it to the latest one. And you needed to change year in the double simpleInterest otherwise the simpleInterest will always be $6,250.